# Queue Class/ IsEmpty method

Tags: c#, queue

So far all this does (at least I hope so lol) is

```
class Queue
{

    private int front = 0; //Creates front and back int holders and an array
    private int back = -1;
    private int[] anArray;

    public Queue(int size) // constructor to get the Queue size 
    {
        anArray = new int[size];
    }

    public bool IsFull
    {
        get // gets to see if the Queue is full ( I assume I did this right, It's full if the back of the queue is equal to -1 of an array)
        {
            return back == anArray.Length - 1;
        }
    }

    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get // It's empty if the back is -1; I think this is where I messed up, I think that when it checks to see if it's empty it also doesn't check if it's empty when I have dequeued the other numbers (or write them off). Would I make something like "Return front == anArray.Length -1;" ? That would check to see when the front (The part being written to console first) hits the end of the array?
        {
            return back == -1;
        }
    }

    public void Enqueue(int valueEnqueue)
    { // Method to Enqueue the variables into the array

        if (IsFull)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            back = back + 1;
            anArray[back] = valueEnqueue;

        }
    }

    public int Dequeue()
    { // Method to dequeue the variables put in
        if (IsEmpty)
        {
            //do nothing
            return 1010101010;
        }
        else
        {
            int dequeue = anArray[front];
            front = front + 1;
            return dequeue;
        }
    }
```

So I guess what my question is, abiding by the normal Queue thinking (First in First out) how do I get it to stop? I keep getting an index out of range error.

Comment: A 140-column line is not very readable. Please break it up.

Comment: How is this unreadable? I skipped lines, etc.

Comment: You're not close, this is more like a stack than a queue.  You have to use the [homework] tag to get the kind of help you need.

Comment: Never had an issue before. If you don't have constructive comments, please don't post. Thank you.

Comment: @Nogg: he's referring to the comments being unreadable, since they're all on one line and you have to scroll.

Comment: @Tyler Treat: Ahh thank you, I had no clue what he was even talking about.

Comment: @Hans Passant: To be more specific, this isn't homework. This is ME trying to teach myself how to do basic data structures. I have no teacher, no friends etc who know this so I come here for help.

Comment: What happens if you enqueue 2 values, then dequeue 2, what value will `back` be then? Most of the questions in the code can be answered by just plain old debugging, with the important question left: What am I doing wrong? And the answer to that is: Everything. Get a good book on data structures if you really want to learn how to do this.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's homework or not. The homework tag is to let people to know that you really want to do it yourself and not use any existing classes. Otherwise you'll get a lot of comments/answers pointing on existing .Net solutions since most of us thinks it's a waste of time to do something yourself that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Why not use: **system.collections.queue**?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx

And if your just want to do so, Try **Reflector** on system.collections.queue and see what's inside.

Comment: @Both of you, Check the comments on my original post.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I suspect you are getting an IndexOutOfRange exception on your Dequeue function which has no limit on the `front` variable, it just keeps incrementing on each call and will eventually exceed the array length.

A queue structure is normally implemented as a circular buffer. Take a look here for more details that might help you with your implementation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

Comment: Right, which is what I have down in my pseudo code. I giant circle. I'm just confused on how to operate this?

Comment: @Nog, your code is not implementing a circular buffer because front/back should wrap around to the begining of the array when they reach the end, currently front for example is ever increasing. Take a look at the wikipedia article I linked to.

Comment: So should I change something in the IsFull method to say when it IS full to start the counter over?

Comment: @Nogg, not only in your IsFull method, but the dequeue as well. I am sure if you work according to the algorithm in the wikipedia article you will significantly improve your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You have a finite array and are expecting infinite capacity.  An array isn't the best container for this, you should use something else to implement your queue, like the List container.

```
Enqueue(item) { list.Add(item); }
Dequeue() 
{ 
  if( !IsEmpty ) 
  {
    var item = list[0];
    list.Remove(item);
    return item;
  }
  return null;
}
IsFull{ get { return false; } }
IsEmpty{ get { return list.Count == 0; }
```